# Can not call "excel.link" package using Rscript.exe

Tags: r

i am new to R and recently i am using 'excel.link' to read excels with macros.

everything is good when i am using R studio.

However, when i call the Rscript using Rscript.exe, it gave me this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvAwb.png)

i have tried to check the library directory and i copy it to every path i can find. But it still doenst work.

Can anyone help on that ?

library(excel.link)

Comment: Are you running Rscript on the same computer as where you run Rstudio? Is it using the same version of R as Rstudio is? You probably just need to run "install.packages("excel.link")` via Rscript to install that package properly.

Comment: Hi , its on the same computer. Now, i am getting this error. > library(excel.link)
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'excel.link' in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):
 number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)

Comment: Ok, its solved. its because the R version. i am using the old version but this package was bulit under a higher version